# How can I start my network log in Safari right from the launch?

Tags: macos, browser, logging, safari, debug

So far I have seen how I can use the Developer menu in Safari in order to analyze my network traffic and how I can preserve the logs. But I have to re-open my browser very often. Therefore I want to know if there is a way that I open Safari every time with logging enabled? I don't want always to go to the menu again and again.

Perhaps I can start the browser from the Terminal with a certain argument or something like that?

Best regards

Comment: What operating system and what safari version? Please [edit] the question tags.

Comment: Dear David
Thanks for your reply. The Mac OS X is 10.14.6
My Safari is 14.01
How should I change the question tags? Would you suggest other tags?

Comment: I hope the new set of tags is better now. Still, please give me some advice.

Comment: @MDoe be patient, it takes time for people to see your question and think of a solution

Comment: Thanks. I delete my other answer.